# Is this the correct to find the sum of even numbers in a Fibonacci series?

Tags: java

is this the correct way to find the sum of even numbers in a fibonacci series.I am getting correct answer while using small range.I am getting a negative value when using an int and a positive number while using long.

```
public class t {
    public static void main(String args[]){
      int i1=1,sum;
      int i2 = 2,temp;
      System.out.println(i1);
      System.out.println(i2);
      sum = i2;

      for(int i = 2; i<4000000; i++){
        //System.out.println(i1+i2);
        if( (i1+i2)%2 == 0 ){
           sum = sum+i1+i2;
        }
        temp = i1;
        i1 = i2;
        i2 = temp+i2;
      }

      System.out.println(sum);
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you test it and find out?

Comment: unless you know what the answer should be, there isn't really any way to know if your code was correct or not

Comment: You'll very likely cross `Integer` limit. Use `Long` to store the sum.

Comment: no using long doesn't solve it

Comment: @rabbitguy the correct answer is 4613732

Comment: @eldhoittangeorge okay. When you run the code what number do you get?

Comment: @rabbitguy the answer i get while using long and int is different when i run with long i am getting 3855046942094 and using int i am getting a negative  value

Comment: @eldhoittangeorge so the real question is why do you get a negative number using int but a positive number when using long. I'm not trying to be condescending here, but have you asked that question yet? I think that will tell you which way is the correct way and why it is

Comment: @rabbitguy i got the answer correct.I got the question wrong the whole time  sorry for the inconvenience and thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all the help guys i got the question wrong.The required program for the answer is this :

```
public class fibeven {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int i1=1;
        int i2 = 2,temp;
    //System.out.println(i1);
    //System.out.println(i2);
        int sum = i2;
        while ((i1+i2)<4000000){
        //System.out.println(i1+i2);
            if((i1+i2)%2==0){
                sum = sum+i1+i2;
            }
            temp = i1;
            i1=i2;
            i2 = temp+i2;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are wondering why you are getting a negative value when using int, it's because the value of `i2` variable at the end of for loop in your code has reached the MAX value of `(2^32)-1`. Once it reaches the max value it goes into negative. Since the MAX of long is `(2^64)-1`, it won't overflow in your loop.